# sqlsrv_query insert php without duplicates

Tags: php, sql-server

i want to insert something throught api and it works perfect
the idea it took data from api and insert to table in ms sql express 2019
but when i run it again it insert the data duplicate , all i want is the new difference only
so how can i fix that?
here is the code

```
<?php


$serverName = "akramlaptop\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectioninfo = array ("Database"=>"Mtdata");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectioninfo);
echo "<table align='center' border='1' bordercolor='black'><form action='' method='POST'>";
echo "<tr bgcolor='#D8D8D8'><td align=left size=3>MAC-Address</td><td size=3>IP</td><td size=3>Name</td>";

use PEAR2\Net\RouterOS;
require_once 'PEAR2_Net_RouterOS-1.0.0b6.phar';
            
define('TYPE_DATA', '!re');
define('TYPE_FINAL', '!done');
define('TYPE_ERROR', '!trap');
define('TYPE_FATAL', '!fatal');
            

$client = new RouterOS\Client('ip', 'user', 'password', port);
echo 'Connected!';

$responses = $client->sendSync(new RouterOS\Request('/ip/arp/print'));

               foreach ($responses as $response) {
                    
                    if ($response->getType() != '!done') {  
        
                        $col1 = $response->getProperty('address');
                        $col2 = $response->getProperty('mac-address');  

$sql = "INSERT INTO arplog (ip, mac) VALUES ('$col1' , '$col2')";

#where $col2 not in (select mac from arplog) 

#$params = array(1, "some data");
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
                
     }
     }
                

#Show inserted Data

$sql2 = "SELECT ip , arplog.mac as [macc] , Name FROM [MTData].[dbo].[ARPLog] left join [MTData].[dbo].[MacOwner] on arplog.Mac = MacOwner.Mac";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
while($row = Sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $row['macc'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['ip'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['Name'] ."</td>";

}       
sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: What is *the new difference*? Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, to clarify your requirement.

Comment: here is an example when i run the php again it insert the same rows so i have them duplicated here is a sample [link] (https://ibb.co/d2g7m7q)